# Why do we need getters when we create ORM class?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I am implementing JPA and using Hibernate to implement ORM. I have created a class to represent a table in my database and private properties to represent the columns of the table with their getters and setters. I successfully fetched and added data to the table with and without the getters.

My question is:
Why do we need getters in this case if the data can be managed without getters?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Setter and Getters are best practices in OOP, you can explore annotation `@Access(AccessType....)`, I don't know if is already deprecated. But about your question many libs need setter and getter for refactoting and reflection processing

Answer (score 0):

Getters/Setters are from the Java Beans convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

**You don't have to use that!**

According to the JPA specification fields in an Entity shouldn't be public.

> The instance variables of a class must be private, protected, or
> package visibility independent of whether field access or property
> access is used. When property access is used, the property accessor
> methods must be public or protected.

But this doesn't mean that you need getters and setters if you can access the data via other methods. Btw. Hibernate allows public fields.